# Django: How to get parameters from QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider the following Django model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_var = models.IntergerField()
```

Whats the best way to get an array of a models parameters from a search results?

Example (not working of course):

```
a = SomeModel.objects.all().some_var
```

would give something like `[3, 4, 1, 9, 1, 2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is existing queryset method called `values_list` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

```
a = SomeModel.objects.all().values_list('some_var', flat=True)
```

We are using `flat=True` so that it will give flat list

```
Entry.objects.values_list('id').order_by('id')
[(1,), (2,), (3,), ...]
Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: That's correct,So the upvote.Wondering, What will be the structure of result?? Comma separated list maybe..??

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi: Yes, a `list` (which are comma separated ;) ) of values in `some_var ` column

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi strictly speaking, the result won't be a list, it would be a queryset. If all you want to do is to iterate over it or pass as a value to some other queryset.filter(), it will behave just the same. But if you want to concatenate it to some other list, use negative indexing (like qs[-2]), you would have to explicitly convert it to a list.

Comment: @НазарТопольський  Thanks :)

Comment: @PrakharTrivedi Actually it will be `QueryList` not `QuerySet`.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I can't find anything named `QueryList` in Django (1.8.13) code. And calling `type(qs.values_list())` yields `ValuesListQuerySet`. So, while it is not a simple `QuerySet`, it is a subclass.

Comment: @НазарТопольський yes. You are correct. In newer versions they are separate and `qs.values_list('...', flat=True)` will yeild FlatValuesListIterable. 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L142

Which is not subclass of Queryset

Answer (score 0):

You can yield the list, this would like the following:

```
foo = [i.some_var for i in SomeModel.objects.all()]
```

But I've been notified that this would waste the memory.

Comment: List comprehension yields a list, not a generator. And if SomeModel has many fields, this would be wasteful in terms of RAM, since Django would have to load everything into memory.